# Github CLI auth refresh command is not opening in browser

Tags: github, wsl-2, github-cli, codespaces, github-codespaces

I'm trying to use this command

```
`gh auth refresh -h github.com -s codespace`
```

it works fine but when it says

```
*"Press Enter to open github.com in your browser"*
```

and when I do it just load the html content inside my terminal.

e.g

```
Skip to content This is a filler to hide the site header
{{ message }}
... more content here
```

I tried navigating to it but no luck getting the codespace permission to be added.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, you could just visit when you get the code from your terminal. `https://github.com/login/device`

ref:
https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2422#issuecomment-1219393463